# Wordpress walker call parent walk() method

Tags: php, wordpress, class, parent

When extending the base Walker class I need to extend the `walk()` method.

However, calling the parent `walk()` method yields no results.

These are the approaches I have tried:

```
public function walk($elements, $max_depth) {
   parent::walk($elements, $max_depth);
}

public function walk($elements, $max_depth) {
   $parent_class=get_parent_class($this);
   $args = array($elements, $max_depth);

   call_user_func_array(array($parent_class, 'walk'), $args);
}
```

It appears to me that as soon as I override the `walk()` things break.

Should this method return some specific value?
Should I call the parent method differently?

Comment: After checking the WP core I saw that the walk() method returns some output, so have you tried like this `return parent::walk($elements, $max_depth);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Walker::walk` will return the string resulting from the walk operation.
What you will get is a text that has been created using the methods `Walker::display_element`, `Walker::start_lvl`, `Walker::start_el` and so on...
What you will get from the parent method is already HTML code probably hard to modify in the right way in a second time, but if you really want to do that:

```
public function walk($elements, $max_depth) {
  $html = parent::walk($elements, $max_depth);

  /* Do something with the HTML output */

  return $html;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you are right and I missed this as I was expecting for parent::walk to be called multiple times from the core for each element. But this is not the case

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment by @TheFallen, the class Walker of Wordpress gives back an output

```
// Extracted from WordPress\wp-includes\class-wp-walker.php
public function walk( $elements, $max_depth ) {
        $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
        $output = '';

        //invalid parameter or nothing to walk
        if ( $max_depth < -1 || empty( $elements ) ) {
            return $output;
        }

        ...
```

So, if you want to extend the class and overwrite the method, **you MUST keep the original behaviour**, returning the output too. My suggestion:

```
class Extended_Walker extends Walker {
     public function walk( $elements, $max_depth ) {
         $output = parent::walk($elements, $max_depth);

         // Your code do things with output here...

         return $output;  
     }
}
```